# Gradle Could not find com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem I want to add com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0. implementation class but gradle reports that it does not find it despite the fact that I added the repositories and the class implementation in both gradle.
I have updated the version of the gradle but gradle still can't find com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0. implementation

Here's my project level's gradle file :

```
plugins {
        id 'kotlin-android'
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'kotlin-kapt'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdk 32
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.wheeler"
            minSdk 23
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding true
            dataBinding = true
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0'
    
    
        def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    
        // ViewModel
        implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version")
        // LiveData
        implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version")
    
        def room_version = "2.4.2"
    
        implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
        implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
        kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1"
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
        implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    }
```

Here's my app's gradle file :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }// Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        }
    dependencies{
        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'

    }}



plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` line to `settings.gradle` now (depending on the `repositoryMode` - new projects in Android Studio default to `PREFER_SETTINGS`, which means it looks for repositories in `settings.gradle` instead of the other gradle files).

For example:

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // add this to get MPAndroidChart
    }
}
```